# Why would a class need an empty method to be called to register it?

Tags: delphi

I'm evaluating existing dependency injection library for Delphi, and settled on this [delphidicontainer](https://code.google.com/p/delphidicontainer/) because of its **simplicity** - it needs only a single [unit file](https://code.google.com/p/delphidicontainer/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src)!

However, there is one thing I don't understand — in [this example file](https://code.google.com/p/delphidicontainer/source/browse/trunk/test/02/DataService.pas) at the bottom:

```
initialization
//with those lines the linked will include the actual code for the services
TCSVDataService.Register;
TPaddedDataService.Register;
```

These `Register` methods are empty, but, if I comment out those two lines in the initialization section, `DIContainer.Get('dataservice') as TDataService` will fail.

Why? What are these **empty** methods for?

Comment: I would not settle on a DI container just because it seems to be simple and only has one unit. It also is limited in ways that you might hit soon. It also does not support interfaces as far as I can see. Unless you are using abstract classes you will not achieve anything that dependency injection is about with using such container.

Comment: @StefanGlienke, oh, yes, it doesn't support Interface and I need to reconsider it a little more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Delphi compiler is smart and will try to eliminate unused code when compiling/linking the code, so from the compiler's point of view, the implementation classes (eg, `TCSVDataService`) in the example are not used anywhere in the program and will be eliminated, so these empty method callings are there to prevent that from happening.